# Can't connect to Remote Desktop over the internet while VPN is active

Tags: networking, vpn, remote-desktop, openvpn, dynamic-dns

I have my personal computer in my home which I have to connect from my laptop at work, I setup it everything to be able to connect over the internet with Dynamic DNS or the external IP, and it works very good, the problem is when I connect to a VPN from my computer at home and try to connect again via RDP.
The current remote desktop session remains connected even if I've changed the IP due to vpn, but the problem is when I have to reconnect, because it can't connect again. I have to enter that computer via TeamViewer and turn off the VPN.

What can I do to prevent this and be able to connect always to my computer even if it has running a VPN?

Comment: any help on this?